# Is there possibly something wrong with (i)mapping the left bracket?

Tags: vimrc, insert-mode, plugin-vim-surround

I've been using the vim-surround plugin for as long as I can remember and have grown accustomed to typing `<c-g>s )` when I want to insert text between brackets. I was writing with the atom editor recently and kind of liked the fact that the editor always inserts a closing bracket if you type an opening one. I realized that producing a similar effect in vim is trivial: I can just use the following mappings:

```
imap ( ()<c-o>i
imap [ []<c-o>i
imap { {}<c-o>i
```

This seemed so obvious that I started wondering why I haven't seen this done very often in people's vimrcs. Are there some possible conflicts / pitfalls related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one it does not work very well with Repeating using `.`. That means, if you create a new buffer start insert mode and type `(foobar` your buffer will show `(foobar)`. How redo the thing using `.`. It will redo only `foobar`.

I thought it would also break the undo sequence, but that does not seem to happen.

To fix the `.` repeating issue, I suggest to use:

`inoremap ( ()<c-g>U<left>`

That needs support for `<C-G>U` in insert mode which has been included in a late Vim 7.4 patch to work and has been requested a couple of years ago on vim_dev.

There might be other gotchas (or people in general just use a snippet/completion plugin instead) and do not care about the details :))

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how your fix works. Any chance of an explanation? (A pointer to where to look in the source would be fine: it doesn't seem self-evident to me that undo and `.` would share code.)

Comment: @Rich Sorry, I did not follow, you want an explanation of what the patch did that implemented `\<C-G>U`?